# build sbt project via artifactory repo: download error: Caught java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: devops, artifactory, sbt-plugin

On buid node I have sbt

```
sbt script version: 1.4.6
```

I have scala project with dependensies in project/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.9.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.7.4")
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.10.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.github.tototoshi" % "sbt-slick-codegen" % "1.4.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.openapitools" % "sbt-openapi-generator" % "5.0.0-beta2")
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.2.9"
```

in project/build.properties

```
sbt.version=1.4.6
```

in Artifactory create 2 remote repo

http://rep.local:80/artifactory/mavenCentral via
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ with type Maven layout maven2-default

and

SBT-scala-sbt.org-plugins via
https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/ with type SBT layout sbt-default

build.sbt

```
name := "some_app"
version := "1.0.0"
scalaVersion := "2.13.3"

resolvers += ("Artifactory" at "http://rep.local/artifactory/libs-release-local").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true)
resolvers += ("maven-central" at "http://rep.local:80/artifactory/mavenCentral").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true)
resolvers += ("ivy" at "http://rep.local/SBT-scala-sbt.org-plugins").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true)

enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin)
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
enablePlugins(CodegenPlugin)

addCompilerPlugin("com.olegpy" %% "better-monadic-for" % "0.3.1")

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-P:bm4:no-filtering:y",
  "-P:bm4:no-map-id:y",
  "-P:bm4:no-tupling:y"
)

buildInfoOptions += BuildInfoOption.BuildTime

Docker / packageName := "new/some_app"
dockerBaseImage := "openjdk:13"
dockerExposedPorts ++= Seq(8080, 8080)
dockerRepository := Some("docker.rep.local")
dockerUpdateLatest := true

libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.all

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).settings(
  SlickCodeGen.settings: _*
)

javaOptions ++= {
  val props = sys.props.toList
  props.filter { case (key, _) => key.startsWith("http") } map {
    case (key, value) => s"-D$key=$value"
  }
}
javacOptions += "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
javaOptions in run += "-Dconfig.resource=application.dev.conf"
javaOptions in reStart += "-Dconfig.resource=application.dev.conf"

fork := true
trapExit := false
connectInput := true
```

try building on build node and returned error

```
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.openapitools:sbt-openapi-generator;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:5.0.0-beta2

[error]   download error: Caught java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) (Connection refused (Connection refused)) while downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openapitools/sbt-openapi-generator_2.12_1.0/5.0.0-beta2/sbt-openapi-generator-5.0.0-beta2.pom
[error]   download error: Caught java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) (Connection refused (Connection refused)) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.openapitools/sbt-openapi-generator/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/5.0.0-beta2/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   download error: Caught java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) (Connection refused (Connection refused)) while downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.openapitools/sbt-openapi-generator/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/5.0.0-beta2/ivys/ivy.xml
```

Try find
https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.openapitools/sbt-openapi-generator/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/5.0.0-beta2/ivys/ivy.xml
via local repo
http://rep.local/SBT-scala-sbt.org-plugins

```
http://rep.local/artifactory/SBT-scala-sbt.org-plugins/org.openapitools/sbt-openapi-generator/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/5.0.0-beta2/ivys/
```

[image]

Exist!

```
$ sbt docker:publish
```

continue to return error...
How solve this problem?

Comment: if off addSbtPlugin("org.openapitools" % "sbt-openapi-generator" % "5.0.0-beta2") - build without problem, error returned after add this SBT Pliggin

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to reach Maven Central, simply appending `resolver` is not going to work.

What you need is to completely *override* the resolvers using `repositories` file and `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true`. See [Proxy Repositories](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html) for the documentation.

#### repositories

```
[repositories]
  local
  libs-release-local: http://rep.local/artifactory/libs-release-local,allowInsecureProtocol
  proxy-central: http://rep.local:80/artifactory/mavenCentral,allowInsecureProtocol
  proxy-ivy: http://rep.local/SBT-scala-sbt.org-plugins,[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext],allowInsecureProtocol
```

#### Resolvers your proxy repository must support

For sbt 1.x, your proxy repository must support at least the following (in addition to any other custom resolvers that your build are using):

```
  maven-central
  sbt-plugin-releases: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/, [organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)([branch]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
```

Note that repo.scala-sbt.org will redirect to Bintray, but where it will redirect is subject to change. In fact, Bintray in general will be shut down on May 1st, 2021.

Comment: make changes, try build - builder cant find com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/1.7.4/ivys/ivy.xml, checked in our repo absent this packege, may be You know publick repo with this pack?

Comment: @NikolayBaranenko I add a section on that.